# fIltering email addresses in a mysqldump file

Tags: mysql, shell

I would like to scramble all email addresses in a mysqldump file and make all the scrambled email addresses unique. Any recommendations?

Comment: What do you mean by scramble? Encrypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base64 if you want to be able to "unscramble" and sha1 or md5 if not.

Comment: Ah, SHA/MD5 for sure... But, I mean more so the script: I guess I could do a line by line gsub with Ruby?

Comment: @Aaron I don't know much Ruby but that should work. You've been a bit short on details. It really matters what your end goal is and if this will become a common process that you have to do often.

Comment: alright I went with this:
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'active_support'
    require 'digest'

    $stdin.each_line do |line|
      s1 = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(16)
      s2 = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(16)
      puts line.gsub(/'([^\s]+?)@([^\s]+?)'/, "'#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{'\1'}--#{s1}")}@#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{'\2'}--#{s2}")}.com'")
    end